# How to check if all element are displayed on web page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html

I have to check if all web elements are presented at web page. If not presented write to log which exactly element is missed.

To write easy test for is not so difficult:

```
public boolean allUIElementsExist() {
    boolean allPresent = true;

    if (!this.tipFrequency.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no tip `should be the same as how often you get paid`");
    }
    if (!this.tipAmount.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no tip 'Borrow equal to the amount of your purchase'");
    }
    if (!this.payBack.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'Pay it back in'");
    }
    if (!this.useTool.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'Use our easy finance tool to quickly explore payment options'");
    }
    if (!this.biWeekly.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'biWeekly'");
    }
    if (!this.semiMonthly.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'semi-monthly (twice a month)'");
    }
    if (!this.month.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'monthly'");
    }
    if (!this.withPayments.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'With payments of:'");
    }
    if (!this.includingLPP.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'including LPP'");
    }
    if (!this.startNewApplication.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'Start new application'");
    }
    if (!this.easyfinancialLink.visibilityOfElementWait()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("no 'easyfinancialLink'");
    }
    return allPresent;
}
```

It works. But to go through all `if` statements doesn't look the best solution.

***How to recreate this code to much better approach?***

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @RobertMoskal it is java. I added appropriate tag.

Comment: What are the tipFrequency, et so members? Are they a class of yours?

Comment: @RobertMoskal All these members are elements of web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the elements a list, iterate through them, and evaluate each one the same way.

Find a way to use [webelement methods](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/master/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to add information about the element into the log message, instead of writing each one by hand. This way, you don't have to write a lot of log messages & they always have the right information about the element (less room for writing errors).

Example: For each element in a list of WebElements named ElementsList, check if element is displayed. If not, write a log fail message with the name of the tag and the text it contained. (If the element has no text, it will just not add any text to the string.)

```
for(WebElement element : ElementsList) {
    if (!this.element.isDisplayed()) {
        allPresent = false;
        Logger.logFail("WebElement not displayed: " + element.getTagName() + " Text: " + element.getText());
  }
```

Comment: Where I able to initialisse this list? At constructor or you have better idea how to achieve this at elegant way?

Comment: @nazar_art You can make the list inside the allUIElementsExist() or pass as an argument. I can't help with more specific Java implementation, just the WebDriver specific parts.